# How to update data in TextBox on the button click event in Android?

Tags: java, android, database

i Create an Android Application,in that Application i insert and delete Normally But i cannot Update it.Am trying to update but i got a error.

```
public Helper(Context ctx) 
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
    int newVersion) 
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS titles");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}    

//---opens the database---
public Helper open() throws SQLException 
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//---closes the database---    
public void close() 
{
    DBHelper.close();
}

//---insert a title into the database---
public long insert(String name) 
{
     ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
     initialValues.put("Name", name);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null,initialValues);
}
//---updates a title---
public long update(String name)
        {
            ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
            args.put("Name",name);

            return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, 
                             "Name" + "=" + name, null);
        }


//---deletes a particular title---
public int delete(String name) 
{
   // return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE,"Name="+name, null);
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE,"Name=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(name)});
}
```

}

My Activity File

```
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table titles (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
     + "Name text not null);";

private final Context context; 

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public Helper(Context ctx) 
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
    int newVersion) 
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS titles");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}    

//---opens the database---
public Helper open() throws SQLException 
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//---closes the database---    
public void close() 
{
    DBHelper.close();
}

//---insert a title into the database---
public long insert(String name) 
{
     ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
     initialValues.put("Name", name);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null,initialValues);
}
//---updates a title---
public long update(String name)
        {
            ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
            args.put("Name",name);

            return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, 
                             "Name" + "=" + name, null);
        }


//---deletes a particular title---
public int delete(String name) 
{
   // return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE,"Name="+name, null);
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE,"Name=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(name)});
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please post the error you get to direct us a little more? Also you seem to have pasted the same code twice in your snippets.

Answer (score 2):

When querying in database,if fields is not number then you have to use '' to enclose the text.Try this.

```
   return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, 
                                 "Name" + "='" + name+"'", null);
```

Comment: oops.I see.How you can update a name by name that is not exists.You have to update name with the id not with the name.